# Intellij Community not able to navigate between files getting "Can not find declaration to go"

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I am using Intellij Community and am having a strange issue.

If I enable the "Enable annotation processing" then not able to navigate between file and getting "Can not find declaration to go" 
But if I uncheck it and "Invalid cache and restart" then able to navigate but then my Annotations like "log" start failing"Cannot resolve symbol 'log'".

I thought the issue was with version 19.3.3 so I moved to IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 but still getting same.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Please, create a new issue in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) and attach a sample project, annotation processor, [IDE logs folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) and a screenshot from **(Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors)**

Comment: Got it working by deleting all the cache files and installing the Lombok plugin manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by deleting all the cache files and installing the Lombok plugin manually